# Winforms C# Using regex search through a text file, find a match, and get the NEXT LINE OF THAT MATCH in a textbox

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

> Lngton KY 40511 ARRIER — LEAVE IF NO RESPONSE LODRESS SERVICE REQUESTED
>
> 604159595920
>
> YAWAR MUHAMMAD YOUNUS
>
> 1263 S CHILLICOTHE RD STE
>
> AURORA OH 43192—8552 695—81

Basically what I want to do is to search for this : **0604156595920** (Some random number of length 12 which will be always above the customer name) and when the match is success then I want to get the next line as an output : **YAWAR MUHAMMAD YOUNUS** (Customer Name).

I am doing it like this because the pattern of the text will be different in each case, the line number will be different and obviously the customer name will be different also.

Here is my code :

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


string strRegex = @"(?<=\d{12}\n)(\w.*)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase |RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
       


        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("SampleText.txt"))
        {   
            Match match = myRegex.Match(line);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(match.Value);   
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fail");
            }

        }
```

This code works fine when the numbers and the name are in same line. But doesn't work for different line.

Another Regex which I tried :

```
(?<=(^\d{13}\n))[A-Za-z].*
```

The above regex works fine in an online regex tester.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks :) Sorry in advance if this is a repeated question. I searched alot on the web but couldn't find any specific answer to my problem.

**EDIT :** Screenshot of regexTester -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ynC-W5aF41cGhJREhtNGhHRnc

Comment: The regex fails because the text is read line by line, there is just no `\n` anywhere in the lines.

Comment: Yes its not that big, about 21 lines per file. I'll try that. Thanks.!

Comment: If you dont mind, can you please post the code..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Non-regex - LINQ - Solution

You can use LINQ to get the line you need with:

```
var s = @"Lngton KY 40511 ARRIER — LEAVE IF NO RESPONSE LODRESS SERVICE REQUESTED

604159595920

YAWAR MUHAMMAD YOUNUS

1263 S CHILLICOTHE RD STE

AURORA OH 43192—8552 695—81";
var res = s.Split(new[] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // Split into lines (you already have it)
             .SkipWhile(p => !(p.Trim().Length == 12 && p.Trim().All(m => Char.IsDigit(m))))
             .Skip(1)
             .Take(1)
             .FirstOrDefault();
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(res))
    Console.WriteLine(res);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/dv8bpc)

Just omit `s` declaration and replace `s.Split(new[] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` in my code with your `File.ReadLines("SampleText.txt")`.

Explanation:

- `s.Split(new[] { "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` - splits the string into lines (you read the file into lines (just make sure there are no empty lines!)
- `SkipWhile` -  above skips all lines that are not 12 chars long (`!(`p.Trim().Length == 12`) and that are not all digits (`p.Trim().All(m => Char.IsDigit(m))`)
- `Skip(1)` - skips the line with the 12-digit number
- `Take(1)` - just takes the current line (the one after the line with just 12-digit number)
- `FirstOrDefault()` - gets the item as a string object or null if not found.

## Regex Solution

```
var res = Regex.Match(s, @"^\p{Zs}*\d{12}\p{Zs}*(?:\r?\n)+(?<MYLINE>.*)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (res.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(res.Groups["MYLINE"].Value);
```

See [another IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8norkI)

If there can be a `#` before then number, replace the regex with

```
@"^\p{Zs}*#?\d{12}\p{Zs}*(?:\r?\n)+(?<MYLINE>.*)"
          ^
```

It will match both 12 digits numbers with and without `#`.

Explanation:

- `^` - start of a ***line*** (becuase `RegexOptions.Multiline` redefines the `^` to match a line start rather than string start)
- `\p{Zs}*` - 0+ horzontal spaces (so as not to jump to another line, can be replaced with `[^\S\r\n]` to match all horizontal whitespace)
- `#?` - one or zero `#`
- `\d{12}` - 12 digits
- `\p{Zs}*` - see above
- `(?:\r?\n)+` - 1 or more linebreaks (either CRLF or just LF style)
- `(?<MYLINE>.*)` - Capture Group "MYLINE": any 0+ characters other than a newline

Comment: Its working :) Thanks alot :) just 1 more thing, if there is an "#" before the number. how can I match it then? Sorry I am new to this code. I didn't understood your code, Otherwise I would do it myself.

Comment: Then the `SkipWhile` would be [`.SkipWhile(p => !(p.Trim().Length == 13 && p.Trim().StartsWith("#") && p.Trim().Substring(1).All(m => Char.IsDigit(m))))`](https://ideone.com/tVtZfn).

Comment: I added a regex solution.

Comment: Thank you sir. Thanks alot :) how can I do that regex will get the next line if it has only characters, otherwise check the next line?

Comment: The LINQ solution works fine, I am going with that one. I just need to get the next line which has ONLY CHARACTERS. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`string strRegex = @"\d{12}\s+(.+)\n$";`

modifiers - Multiline

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\SampleText.txt");
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(s, @"\d{12}\s+(.+)\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach(var i in mc)
{
  Match m = Regex.Match(i.ToString(), @"\s+(.+)*", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Comment: Read the complete at one go

Comment: If you advise using `RegexOptions.Multiline` you are not sure what the regex does.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the foloweing 'regex':

```
(?<=\d{12})[\n\s]*(.+)
```